# RestKit Can't Map

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I can not seem to figure out how to map the following JSON, I am trying to map the hostedLargeUrl from the response. I am not sure what to do for this issue, and would like to apologize if my info is not detailed enough. Not too sure what type of details you would need.
Thank you in advance.

```
images: [
{
imageUrlsBySize: {
90: "http://lh4.ggpht.com/ZXiwjS55Zk7oBu6GWaVr0HAqIPKumXwBfGtzsCWEFdrJSOXiCcC-I3TpUwrXBnP_DPNuBm-ib-4-3aXbs4mfXA=s90-c",
360: "http://lh4.ggpht.com/ZXiwjS55Zk7oBu6GWaVr0HAqIPKumXwBfGtzsCWEFdrJSOXiCcC-I3TpUwrXBnP_DPNuBm-ib-4-3aXbs4mfXA=s360-c"
},
hostedLargeUrl: "http://i.yummly.com/Pasta-with-garlicky-broccoli-rabe-305651-270310.l.jpg",
hostedSmallUrl: "http://i.yummly.com/Pasta-with-garlicky-broccoli-rabe-305651-270310.s.jpg"
}
```

Here is my code:

```
+ (RKMapping *)recipeDetailMapping
{
    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RecipeDetails class]];

    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{

                                                  @"attribution.text" : @"attributionText",
                                                  @"images.hostedLargeUrl" : @"images"
                                                  }];



    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"ingredientLines",
                                             @"name",
                                             @"totalTime",

                                             ]];




    return mapping;

}
```

RecipeDetails

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *ingredientLines;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *totalTime;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *attributionText;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *images;
```

Last bit of code

```
- (void)loadRecipeDetails
{
    NSIndexSet *statusCodeSet = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful);

    RKMapping *mapping = [MappingProvder recipeDetailMapping];



    NSString *resourcePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/v1/api/recipe/%@", self.recipeInfo.recipeId];

    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping
                                                                                            method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                       pathPattern:resourcePath
                                                                                           keyPath:nil
                                                                                       statusCodes:statusCodeSet];










    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipe/%@?_app_id=%@&_app_key=%@&requirePictures=true", self.recipeInfo.recipeId
                                       ,Yummly_APP_ID , Yummly_API_kEY ]];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];



    RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                                                        responseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptor]];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {




       self.recipeData = mappingResult.array;


        [self updateUI];


        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];





    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", operation.HTTPRequestOperation.responseString);

        [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Request Failed"];
    }];



    [operation start];





}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source data is in an array and you need to deal with that in some way.

Option 1.
Change the property to `NSArray *images;`

Option 2.
Add a custom method `setImageArray:` and implement it to extract the first image and store it. Then change the mapping to use a destination key of `imageArray`.

Other options really require a different object graph...